# passing array from jquery to mandrill api to send mail

Tags: jquery, mandrill

I have an array of email addresses, like so:

```
var to = '[user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com,user3@gmail.com]';
```

I am passing it to a javscript script to send mail via the Mandrill api,as follows:

```
function log(obj) {
    $('#response').text(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

// create a new instance of the Mandrill class with your API key
var m = new mandrill.Mandrill('BK0z-Ark1NAZCkc2PwbSRw');
var from_email = "user4@gmail.com";
var to = '[user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com,user3@gmail.com]';
// create a variable for the API call parameters
var params = {
    "message": {
        "from_email":from_email,
        "to":[{"email":to}],
        "subject": "Sending a text email from the Mandrill API",
        "text": "I'm learning the Mandrill API at Codecademy, it's very difficult."
    }
};

function sendTheMail() {
// Send the email!
alert('this is a mail script');
    m.messages.send(params, function(res) {
        log(res);
    }, function(err) {
        log(err);
    });
}
```

When to "to" variable is just one email address: "user1@gmail.com" there is no problem.

when I attempt to pass it as array,as above, the json response is:

```
[{"email":"[user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com,user3@gmail.com]","status":"invalid","_id":"1e25584e26c7447bb40b14dfc6b4f7fc","reject_reason":null}]
```

and the mail is not sent.

How can I fix this and pass the array correctly? I have tried every combination, I can think of ....

Answer (score 0):

```
"to": [
            {
                "email": "recipient.email@example.com",
                "name": "Recipient Name"
            }
        ],
```

Use JSON instead of array in 'to'.

Comment: Thanks I know that is what I am supposed to do, so how do I pass multiple emails from my javascript array into that? That's my question. The email addresses I want to use are already in a javascript array, you see. Also, "multiple" is important not just one.

Comment: var to = '[{"email" : user1@gmail.com , "name" : user1},
           {"email" : user2@gmail.com , "name" : user}];

Comment: If you have an array then you have to convert it into JSON first same as above format.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your assistance, how do I do that? I have tried JSON.stringify(). The emails are already in a javascript array, so I ma stuck at that  point. I have tried emails = [] JSON.stringify(emails) but no joy. How do I convert the array, in my code above, into a suitable object to pass to the mandrill email sending bit. I know what the end result should be, how do I get there? My question is how, not what. I cannot hard code it because there may be hundreds of email addresses.

Comment: var to = '[user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com,user3@gmail.com]';
var obj = {};


for(i in to){
   obj[i] = to[i];
} 

Now you will have a JSON in obj and you can pass it to the mandrill call now.

Comment: your javascript array is not correct. it should read as

to = ['user1@gmail.com','user2@gmail.com','user3@gmail.com']

correct this first and then proceed with my code in last comment

Comment: Thank you, my question is still how! I don't know how to do this. I am afraid you are going to have to spell it out for me. With the code that you propose above =>  to = ['user1@gmail.com','user2@gmail.com','user3@gmail.com'] followed by
var obj = {}; for(i in to){ obj[i] = to[i]; }
(which does not work, probably I have done it wrongly) what is the object that is passed to mandrill? to or obj? So is it  "to":[{"email":to}], or  "to":[{"email":obj}]? I have tried both and neither works! I appreciate your kind assistance.

Comment: You have to send me the code for how you are creating a array of emails. you said that this array is made dynamically. If this is an array then why are you converting the array to string.

Comment: thanks that's very kind of you, how can I send it? My email address is richardwi@gmail.com if you want to ping me I can send by return.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30970/discussion-between-chetan-bhopal-and-user1903663)